# Programmatically check if core data persistent store contains records (Objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I need to programmatically check if core data persistent store is empty or not - i.e. are there any data/records or not. I would like to know if there is possibility to check if persistent store is empty or not without doing fetch request for some entity.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if managedobjectcontext is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893134/check-if-managedobjectcontext-is-empty)

Comment: @AndréSlotta, Thanks, I know that it is possible to fetch for a certain entity, and detect if it contains data or not. But I would like to know if there is possibility to check if persistent store is empty or not without doing fetch request for some entity.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you not want to fetch?  It seems the most expedient solution.

Comment: @pbasdf, because I am not sure which entity to fetch to be sure that core data is empty or not - perhaps checking one entity is not enough to be sure that the DB is empty, that's why I would like to know if anybody has tried to check the core data emptiness w/o fetch for some entity.

Comment: I’m not aware of any easy way to do this.  I think the best bet will be to iterate through all the entities and check each one is empty.  If you are concerned about fetching data unnecessarily, use `count(for: NSFetchRequest)` rather than `fetch(_: NSFetchRequest)`.  If you really want to avoid this, you might be able to use NSPersistentStore metadata.  You will have to set your own key to indicate when objects have been added to the store and to clear it if you delete all the objects.